# How to pipe output of certain commands to a pager with zsh?

Tags: command-line, svn, zsh, alias

I am frequently working with subversion in console using its client `svn`. One of common tasks is viewing `svn log`; however its output is usually pretty massive despite of `--limit` option. I would like to pipe the output to my `$PAGER` (which is `less` to be exact), just like `git log` does. I wonder if this can be achieved with `zsh` advanced completion features; i.e. whenever I type

```
svn log path1 path2 path3<Enter>
```

the piping construction will be appended:

```
svn log path1 path2 path3 | $PAGER
```

This resembles to me the way aliases work, but from the "other side".

Is this possible in zsh?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with a shell function. Just put this in your `~/.zshrc`.

```
svn() {
    if [ "$1" = "log" ]
    then
        command svn "$@" | less -FX
    else
        command svn "$@"
    fi
}
```

I've tested that with `bash` and `p4`, but it should work the same with `zsh` and `svn`. The `-FX` options to `less` tell it to quit if the entire file fits on the first screen and not to switch to the alternate screen. This makes it appear that `less` wasn't used at all if the output fits on one screen.

Comment: I like the solution.

Comment: Thank you from 12 years in the future.